# Capitalizing letters through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code

```
<body>
<h2>Text Changer</h2>
<p>The following program will change the way your text looks.</p>

<p>Uppercase/Lowercase: <input id = "upperLower" type="checkbox" onclick = "capitalize()" /></p>

<p id = "lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
```

JS code

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
});

var str;
str = document.getElementById('lorem').value;

function capitalize() {
    if (document.getElementById('upperLower').checked) {
        document.writeln(str.toUpperCase());
    }
    if (document.getElementById('upperLower').unchecked) {
        document.writeln(str.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

So with this code, I am trying to get the function to capitalize/uncapitalize the lorem text with the checking/unchecking of the box. However, it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone help me out with this? Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* Something that is checked cannot be unchecked.

Comment: `document.writeln` - the 90's called

Answer (score 4):

`p` does not have the attribute `value`. You can use `textContent` or `innerText` instead.

Change

```
document.getElementById('lorem').value;
```

To

```
document.getElementById('lorem').innerText;
```

```js
'use strict';
function capitalize() {
  var str = document.getElementById('lorem').innerText;

  if (document.getElementById('upperLower').checked) {
    document.getElementById('lorem').innerText = str.toUpperCase();
  }else{
    document.getElementById('lorem').innerText = str.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Text Changer</h2>
<p>The following program will change the way your text looks.</p>

<p>Uppercase/Lowercase: <input id="upperLower" type="checkbox" onclick="capitalize()" /></p>

<p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the capitalise() function as follows:

```
function capitalize() {
var str;
str = document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML;

if (document.getElementById('upperLower').checked) {
    document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML=str.toUpperCase();
}else{
    document.getElementById('lorem').innerHTML=str.toLowerCase();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of your code. You need to use `innerText` to fetch and update the content. And you can use `checked` property to identify if the checkbox is checked or not:

```js
function capitalize(elem) {
  var textEntered = document.getElementById("lorem").innerText;
  if (elem.checked) {
    document.getElementById("lorem").innerText= textEntered.toUpperCase();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("lorem").innerText= textEntered.toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Text Changer</h2>
<p>The following program will change the way your text looks.</p>

<p>Uppercase/Lowercase: <input id="upperLower" type="checkbox" onclick="capitalize(this)" /></p>

<p id="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```